# UITableView slightly goes up when keyboard hides

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

I am using UITableView (chatTable) along with UITabBar (chatTabBar) and one textField inside imageView. I am using autolayout. I used the following code to change the views when keyboard appears and disappears.

```
        - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
        {
            NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

            // get animation info from userInfo
            NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
            CGRect keyboardFrame;
            [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
            [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

            // resize the frame
            [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

                self.keyboardHeight.constant =  keyboardFrame.size.height - TABBAR_HEIGHT ;
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:nil];

            if ([chatData count] != VALUE_ZERO)
            {
                [chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([chatData count] - VALUE_ONE) inSection:VALUE_ZERO] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
            }
        }

        - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
        {
            NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

            // get animation info from userInfo
            NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
            CGRect keyboardFrame;
            [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
            [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

            // Set view frame
            [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                self.keyboardHeight.constant -= keyboardFrame.size.height - TABBAR_HEIGHT;
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:nil];
        }
```

Now when I press return the tableview goes up a littel bit (from screen 2 to screen 3). keyboardHeight is the bottom space constraint between the tabBar and main view.

[image]
(screen 2)

---

[image]
(screen3)

I have tried many things but I can't able to find why the tableview is going up for a while. (problem is there is no smooth animation.) (Note: I have put delay as 2.0 only to show what happens in following screenshot(screen 3) othewise it's value would be 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're changing the table view frame when the keyboard appears, which is wrong. You need to change the contentInset property of the table view, instead of meddling with frames.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
  CGFloat height = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
  UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, height, 0.0f);
  _tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets;
  _tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
  UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  _tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets;
  _tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the positioning of your table view is incorrect due to the autolayout constraints you've set. You should start by digging into that. Not really sure what do you mean by the value of **height**, it's keyboard height - tab bar height, frankly.

Comment: It is not working, I am getting the same problem. The tableView frame is already changed as I am changing the constraints. And if I add the shrinking which should not be the case.

Comment: No, you don't have to change the frame, only change the content insets. Don't change the constraints at all, just modify the insets as in the example I've posted

Comment: AutoLayout of table is correct as the scollindicator is placed properly.

Comment: It is working. but how can I move my imageView up...(i am not getting contentInset for imageView).

Comment: Set it as a tableFooterView for your tableview

Comment: But I don't know if it is common practice. What if I have only one message in chat. By the way any other solution to remove that jerk after the keyboard hides?

Comment: It's a **solution** to your current task. There is absolutely nothing wrong with using a view with text field in header or footer of your table view. Whether it's a common practice or not makes no sense, most of programming tasks do not fall under the "common practice" field anyway.

Comment: What do you mean only one message in chat? And what "jerk" are you referring to?

Comment: But If I have only one message in chatTable then it's footer will not be properly placed.

Comment: one message means only one cell present in tableView.by "jerk" I was reffering to the main problem (tableView slitly going up).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, this way having it as a footer might be problematic, will have to think this through. I've had a similar case, but my text field was in the header, so this wasn't the problem

Comment: ok thanks for answer...If you have any other solution please reply.

Comment: Well, I know the way to solve this without using the auto layout, would that do?

Comment: Perhaps you'll find the solution with autolayout anyway. The height you were asking about is keyboard height - tabbar height - your image view with text field height. Animation duration is available via `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey`

Comment: Yes of course If I can't find any solution then I will have to use it...(but I prefer autolayout.)

Comment: the **offset** of your image view will be equal to keyboard height - tabbar height. and the content inset will be the **offset** - image view height

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with contentInset property. I am using contentInset as mentiond by the @Eugene and also changing the `constant` property of bottom constraint of the textfiled to move up and doen whenever keyboard is shown and hidden.