# Adjusting view for messaging app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm running into a few minor issues with my chat application which consists of a table view and textfield.  When I tap on the textfield, the keyboard pops up and pushes the table view and textfield up so I can type my message.  However, because the table view goes up, once i send the message, the message is displayed in the first cell in the table view and ends up being hidden because its out of view, unless I hide the keyboard.  What do you guys think is the proper way of doing this?  I'm thinking the textfield should be the only thing that moves up when i expand the keyboard, rather than the entire view?  Anyone done something similar to this?

Here is the code I'm using to adjust the view

```
- (void)moveView:(NSDictionary*)userInfo up:(BOOL)up
{
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&animationCurve];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&animationDuration];

    // Get the correct keyboard size to we slide the right amount.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    int y = keyboardFrame.size.height * (up ? -1 : 1);
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, y);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your textfield up / down as well as resize your table view along with showing / hiding keyboard other than just moving whole view up and down. In any case your whole table view will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to scroll the tableview immediately after adding the new cell. You should also reposition the textfield when keyboard shows and hides. **You have to use contentInset property.**

You can refer this question [UITableView slightly goes up when keyboard hides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223869/uitableview-slightly-goes-up-when-keyboard-hides/22224099?noredirect=1#comment33747890_22224099). Explore contentInset property if you are not familiar with it and let me know if you need any furthur clarification.

Comment: I'm looking at the solution in your link and I'm having a hard time understanding this line
`CGFloat height = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;`

Comment: `[[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame].size.height;`  will give you the height of the keyboard and `self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height` is the height of the tabbar.

Comment: But why subtract?  What does the difference give you?  Also doesn't UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey give you a CGRect at the start frame -  while the keyboard is hidden?

Comment: Here `self.keyboardHeight` is IBOutlet of the bottom constraint of textfield and I am changing the constant property of that constraint. So it will change the position when keyboard is shown and hides.

Comment: Yes you can only use the height of the keyboard. I am subtracting because I am having the tabbar and the textfield, and the bottom constraint value of the textfield is already equal to the tabbar height.

Comment: By subtracting the keyboard height from the tab bar height, what does that value represent?

Comment: If keboard = 50 and tabbar = 20 then ans= 30. Here I just want to set my bottom constraint of textfield so that tabbar also can be shown. You can reset bottom constraint to zero.

Comment: Don't look at that line of code as I am changing the constant property of constraint (here I use negative value to reset constant property).

Comment: You can play with that and find what suits you well. Also don't forget to use contentInset for tableView.